# Regex: find a variable number sequence

Tags: regex

I am looking for a specific sequence of numbers in a line. I can best explain with an example:

```
00001 # first search criteria - line 1
00010 # second search criteria - line 2
```

So every line has 5 digits of either 0 or 1. I am looking for the combination of all 0 except for 1 digit that can be a 1. This 1 can be in any position of the 5 digits.

The regex code I have for 5 digits of 0 is

```
^((0\s*?){5}) # there may be spaces between the numbers
```

The line 1 case above would be selected with following regex code:

```
^((0\s*?){4})\s*(1)
```

My question is how I could write in regex code the changing position of 1 to cover the 5 cases/positions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead based regex for this:

```
^(?=[0\s]*1[0\s]*$)(?:\s*[01]\s*){5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO5jO3/2)

Lookahead `(?=[0\s]*1[0\s]*$)` will enforce only single `1` at any position in input where as `(?:\s*[01]\s*){5}` will make sure that input has only 0 and 1 with 5 digits length also allowing white-spaces anywhere.

Comment: If there are no spaces between the numbers, this works. How can I adjust to allow for spaces (even tabs), as I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two conditionals.
First one insures `1` is not found again.
Second one insures `1` is found.

`(?:((?(1)(?!))1)|0){5}(?(1)|(?!))`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      (                             # (1 start)
           (?(1) (?!) ) 1
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  0
 ){5}
 (?(1) | (?!) )
```